# Search data from dataset

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, filter, datatable, dataset

I want to search record based on following fields

```
    P_num ,P_name, P_dob,P_code
```

I am using more than 4 tables to retrive data,
I have created dataset called `P_search` and i want to fill data into dataset and thsn display it according to which field is selected for search purpose.

Suggest me to write code by creating own function in which all fields and a boolean variable will be taken as parameters

Please help me to write code using VB.net.

I am very new to VB.net. Is ther anyone who can help me giving above code.

Thank You In advance

Comment: I don't really quite follow: can you please edit your question to give an example of what you mean? If you could show some sample tables, and show us what you want to be able to call, and what you want it to return, then maybe it will be easier to show you how to do what you want.

Comment: I want to write function in which i can retirve records according to fields mentioned above and display it. For example if record is search as per P_num, If Pnum is provided than data belongs to that p_num should display.

Answer (score 1):

You use [DataTable.Select Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/det4aw50.aspx#Y311)

```
Private Sub GetRowsByFilter()

    Dim table As DataTable = DataSet1.Tables("Orders")

    ' Presuming the DataTable has a column named Date.
    Dim expression As String
    expression = "Date > #1/1/00#"
    Dim foundRows() As DataRow

    ' Use the Select method to find all rows matching the filter.
    foundRows = table.Select(expression)

    Dim i As Integer
    ' Print column 0 of each returned row.
    For i = 0 to foundRows.GetUpperBound(0)
       Console.WriteLine(foundRows(i)(0))
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: I dnt want console application. i am designing website

Comment: Console application is just for understanding example, you can do the same for website.